# Removing modal content after closing

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

myModal displays an image. After I close, it doesn't clear the data from previous modal. Here is what i have done so far.

```
<a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-remote-image="resources/uploads/<?= $s->photo_url; ?>">
    <i class="fa fa-image"></i>
</a>
```

Modal body :

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Slide</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('<img class="img-responsive" src="'+ e.relatedTarget.dataset.remoteImage+ '">').load(function() {
        $(this).appendTo($('#myModal .modal-body'));
    });
});

$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e){ 
    $(this).removeData();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(this).removeData('bs.modal');
```

Without seeing more of the surrounding code it is hard to tell. But you could just empty the modal:

```
$('#myModal .modal-body').empty()
```

Comment: Still same. It passes the new image to bottom of the previous one.

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: latest version 3.3.6